# Java do while loop with multiple conditions not executing properly

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have to write a Magic 8 ball program that will account for user input errors and I have to use a loop to do that.

```
boolean okay;
    do {
        System.out.printf("What is your question?\n");
        questionStr = keyboard.nextLine();
        int length = questionStr.length();
        if (questionStr.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Not allowed.");
            okay = false;
        } else if (!(questionStr.charAt(length - 1) == '?')) {
            System.out.println("Add question mark.");
            okay = false;
        } else if (questionStr.length() > 60) {
            okay = false;
        }
        okay = true;
    } while (!okay);
```

When I run the code and make it an empty string, it does print out not allowed however it still runs the rest of the code and does not loop back and ask "What is your question?" The same happens with the question mark; it prints out "Add question mark" but does not loop back like it is supposed to. If I make a question longer than 60 characters, the code still executes and does not loop back and continue asking the user "What is your question?" until the code is less than 60 characters. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Add `else` before `okay = true;`.

Comment: Elementary debugging would uncover the problem with setting `okay` to `true`in any case in the first minute. This is not an online debugger really

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Move `okay = true;` **before** your `if` statements that negate it,

```
okay = true;
if (questionStr.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println("Not allowed.");
    okay = false;
} else if (!(questionStr.charAt(length - 1) == '?')) {
    System.out.println("Add question mark.");
    okay = false;
} else if (questionStr.length() > 60) {
    okay = false;
}
```

As posted, you unconditionally set `okay` to `true` before your condition `while (!okay);` and thus the loop always ends.